# Is Java's EnumSet mutable?

Tags: java

Is there any way to modify an `EnumSet` object? It seems that (for example) `EnumSet.add` is inherited from `AbstractSet` and that throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Yet it looks as if `EnumSet` is modifiable; otherwise why bother having a `clone()` method, and why would Guava have `Sets.immutableEnumSet()`? Is there a method of `EnumSet` that's escaped my mind?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes `EnumSet` is modifiable. If you want to create an immutable `EnumSet` then go for [immutableEnumSet](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#immutableEnumSet(E,E...)).

- Returns an immutable set instance containing the given enum elements. Internally, the returned set will be backed by an `EnumSet`.
- The iteration order of the returned set follows the enum's iteration order, not the order in which the elements appear in the given collection.

> Parameters:
> elements - the elements, all of the same enum type, that the set should contain
>
> Returns:
> an immutable set containing those elements, minus duplicates

Comment: If EnumSet is modifiable, can you give me an example of how to modify an EnumSet instance?

Comment: @DodgyCodeException What do you mean?  You modify it like any `Set`, with `add`, `remove`, etc.  Just because the `EnumSet` class doesn't override `add` or `remove` doesn't mean its _implementations_ don't override those methods.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks. I was misled by the implementation, which said that EnumSet.add was inherited from AbstractSet.add - and the latter certainly throws an UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: or you can use `Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(`

Answer (score 5):

`EnumSet` is just an abstract class. It's implementation overrides `add` method which makes it mutable and hence the below is possible

```
EnumSet<MyEnum> enumSet = EnumSet.of(MyEnum.A);
enumSet.add(MyEnum.B);


private static enum MyEnum {
   A,B,C;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`EnumSet` is an abstract class which has implementations `RegularEnumSet` and `JumboEnumSet`. Both impement `add` and are mutable. `EnumSet.of(...)` choose `RegularEnumSet` or `JumboEnumSet` depending on the number of enums.